# Angular datatables disappear when removing row using the angular way

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I have created a angular datatable using the angular way (ng-repeat) by l-lin.

My ng-repeat list is in below format:

```
$scope.list = [[...],[...],[...],[...]];
```

By using the below function with ng-click and $index I am able to remove one item from the list

```
  $scope.deleteItem = function (index) {
    $scope.list.splice(index, 1);
}
```

However sometimes the datatables will disappear after removing the item. Do i need to rerender the datatable? (the angular way won't work with .rerender())

Comment: Can we have a look at some more code .to understand the problem

Comment: so basically the list has removed the particular item but in UI it doesn't show probably

Comment: @Ron please share your html ng-repeat section code

Comment: @Ron can you put your datatable code and html.